# React useEffect only renders after going to another page and getting back

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react and i am trying to do a little project, and i came up with this loop :

```
  useEffect(() => {
    cards = [];
    for (i = 0; i < CardData.length; i++) {
      cards.push(<Card info={CardData[i]} key={CardData[i].title} />);
    }
  }, []);
```

For navigation between different pages, I use `react-router-dom` but in order for that loop to execute once, i need  to click on a `<Link />` to another page, and after that I need to get back to the original page in order for that loop to execute.

What am I doing wrong and why does my app have this behavior?
P.S. that data variable in the `useState` hook is an array of objects and I get it from another file using: `import data from "./../dummyData.js";`

Comment: Seems like you don't need useEffect in this case. You can use CardData.map(.... directly in the return.

Comment: `useEffect` can be used to make any side effects like CRUD operations. I don't think you are doing that here. Like @FLash suggested, you can directly use `CardData.map((props) => <Card info={props.i} key={props.title} />);`

Answer (score 0):

Please post your code where you are setting the state and also your return().

Else, at the moment, your useEffect is not triggering an immediate render.

Add a line after the for loop to set state by destructuring the cards array.